# PHP - preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some HTML content and I would like to replace a tag:

```
<span class='c1'>MY TEXT</span>
```

And keep MY TEXT.
I tried with:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(<span class=\'c1\'>)(.*)(<\/span>)/', '$2', $my_string);
```

But the closed tag still remains?
Can you help me and EXPLAIN where is my mistake? I would like to improve myself!
Thank you

Comment: I guess .* matches closing tags too...

Comment: It probably matches on the closing tag too with `(.*)`, as a test you could do something like `([^<]*)`. If this works, you could use lookaheads to get the result.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, I don't see what the problem is, but just as a note, some of the parentheses are not needed, e.g. you could use this: `preg_replace('/<span class=\'c1\'>(.*)<\/span>/', '$1', $my_string);`

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html ....

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Or you just add "U" tag to the regex. (Ungreedy mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a lazy match `(.*?)` instead of a greedy match `(.*)`.

Greedy match means it will match *as much as possible* before finishing, so if you have another `</span>` somewhere, it will match that instead.  For example:

**Using a greedy match:**

```
<span class='c1'>MY TEXT</span><span class='c1'>MY OTHER TEXT</span>
                 ^--greedy match will go from here to here--^
```

**Using a lazy match:**

```
<span class='c1'>MY TEXT</span><span class='c1'>MY OTHER TEXT</span>
                 ^-lazy^                        ^---lazy----^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$result = preg_replace('/(\<span class=(\'|\")?c1(\'|\")?\>)(.*)(\<\/span\>)/i', '$4', $my_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your match-all group probably consumes too much and you see another `</span>` from the trailing content.
You should try

```
$result = preg_replace('/(<span class=\'c1\'>)(.*?)(<\/span>)/', '$2', $my_string);
```

which uses an ungreedy match-all (`.*?`).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net), it's the best solution for manipulating HTML elements.

**Example:**

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('<span class="c1">MY TEXT</span>');
$text = $html->plaintext;
```

Or if you have an entire HTML document (rather than just a snippet of HTML):

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('html goes here');
$text = $html->find('span.c1', 0)->plaintext; // Find text from first <span> with the class 'c1'
```

It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you perfect result:

```
preg_match_all('/<span(.*?)class=\'c1\'>(.*?)<\/span>/', '$2', $my_string, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
   echo $result[0][$i];
}
```

Comment: Good One bro..got exactly what i wanted